# Frame by frame with QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, video, frame

I'm trying to implement a "frame by frame" function for users on the [Video Widget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimediawidgets-videowidget.html) from Qt Examples, but I didn't find how to do that with [QMediaPlayer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qmediaplayer.html). I also want to get MetaData of a video file (e.g. how many frames per second, duration, etc...) but .metadata("Duration") function give nothing.

Is QMediaPlayer the right class to use ? If yes, how can I do what I want ?

If not what class do I have to use ?

Thanks for your help.